# Bug, or user error? Creating a border on a cropped Mat Image doesn't render the rightmost border line correctly

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using the Java bindings for `OpenCv` and attempting to add a border to an image that has been cropped. However, while the border draws 100% as expected on the full image, it doesn't draw the left side correctly if I crop the source image.

For example: Grumpy Cat

[image]

Now, to add the border, I've more or less copied the code from the [OpenCV border tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html).

e.g.

```
public class main {
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      try{
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
         Mat source = Highgui.imread("images\\original.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);


         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         // make the border with a size of 10px for each side 
         Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(source, destination, 10, 10, 
                                10, 10, Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(255,0,0));

         // Save the image
         Highgui.imwrite("images\\borderWrap.jpg", destination);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
   }
}
```

Running this code, I get a nice border with 10px on each side as expected.

[image]

Now, If I modify the code to first crop the image, this stop working as expected.

```
public class main {
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      try{
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
         Mat isource = Highgui.imread("images\\original.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

         // crop the image to half of its width
         Mat source = new Mat(isource, new Rect(0, 0, 480, 540)); 

         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         // make the border with a size of 10px for each side 
         Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(source, destination, 10, 10, 
                                10, 10, Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(255,0,0));

         // Save the image
         Highgui.imwrite("images\\borderWrap.jpg", destination);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
   }
}
```

[image]

It doesn't draw the right side of the border. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Now, If I do another call to `copyMakeBorder`, but this time with just the rightmost border param having a value it *will* fill it in correctly.

```
 // First border pass (doesn't draw right size)
 Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(source, destination, 10, 10, 
                                                10, 10, Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
                                                new Scalar(255,0,0));

 //Second border pass -- only rightmost param is supplied a size      
 Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(destination, destination, 0, 0, 
                                                        0, 10, Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
                                                        new Scalar(255,0,0));
```

[image]

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: +1 Great question. You've specified your intentions, your expected results, and the actual results. Keep it up!

Comment: +1, this question can be made as model question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Imgproc.copyMakeBorder` javadoc:

> When the source image is a part (ROI) of a bigger image, the function will try to use the pixels outside of the ROI to form a border. To disable this feature and always do extrapolation, as if src was not a ROI, use borderType BORDER_ISOLATED.

So if you switch to `Imgproc.BORDER_ISOLATED` constants it should work fine (and it does):

```
Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(source, destination, 10, 10, 10, 10,
        Imgproc.BORDER_ISOLATED, new Scalar(255,0,0));
```